# Inserting all selected items to database from asp listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, listbox

I am trying to add different fields along with all selected items from listbox to database using stored procedure and @@identity.

But only the first selected value gets inserted into the table. When I try to use for loop it gives error that there are too many arguments in the stored procedure.

I am new to asp.net and would appreciate any help possible.

Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[InsertProcessUnit]
(
 @ProcessUnitName Varchar(50),
 @ProcessUnitNumber  int,
 @ProcessUnitInspected bit,
 @RefineryAreaName Varchar(50),
 @System_id int
) 
As
 Begin

 BEGIN TRANSACTION
   INSERT INTO Process_Units (Process_Unit_Name, Process_Unit_Number, Process_Unit_Inspected, Refinery_Area_id) 
   VALUES (@ProcessUnitName, @ProcessUnitNumber,@ProcessUnitInspected,(SELECT Refinery_Area_id from Refinery_Area where Refinery_Area_Name Like @RefineryAreaName))
   DECLARE @DataID int;
   SET @DataID = @@IDENTITY
   INSERT INTO PU_Systems (Process_Unit_id, System_id) VALUES (@DataID, @System_id)
 COMMIT
End

Aspx.cs code:

try
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.CommandText = "InsertProcessUnit";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProcessUnitNumber", PUNumberTxtbox.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProcessUnitName", PUNameDdl.SelectedItem.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProcessUnitInspected", PUInspectedDdl.SelectedItem.Value);
                command.Parameters.Add("@RefineryAreaName", SqlDbType.Text).Value = RefAreaNameTxtbox.Text;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@System_id", ListBox1.SelectedItem.Value);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   connection.Close();
            Label1.Text = "Successfully Inserted !!";
        }
```

Comment: Seems that you need to clear `SqlParameter` for every iteration (either using for or foreach loop). Since the listbox doesn't iterated, by default it retrieve first available data to be processed into DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SelectedIndices property:

```
foreach (int i in listbox.SelectedIndices)
{
    listbox.Items[i].ToString() ...
}
```

Or

```
foreach (var item in listbox.SelectedItems)
{
    MessageBox.Show(item.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the   command.Parameters.Clear() before settign the parameters on your c# code.